# Link with some unknow string when parameter exist

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, parameters

I have some strange issue, when try to set parameter in string(redirect). I don't know where the last chars came from

```
public String register(){
    // ...
    return "/login?correctReg=true?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

And output link:

> .../login.xhtml?correctReg=true%3F

Where this %3F came from?

Answer (score 0):

The second `?` after `correctReg=true` is encoded automatically to `%3f`.  You probably mean...

```
return "/login?correctReg=true&faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
```

... with `&`.